# C++: Generic if statement supporting std::complex<double> AND double

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading, complex-numbers

We want to enable complex step differentiation in our C++ code. To this end, we introduce a generic template parameter `template<typename number>`, where number should be default set to `double` or if requested to `std::complex<double>`. In certain functions, we also have `if` statements, which should be also callable with complex-type values. Is there a smarter way than the one below in the MWE to support both -- the comparison of `double` values as well as real parts of `std::complex<double>` in `if` statements? Many thanks in Advance!

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <complex>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std::complex_literals;

template<typename number>
double make_real(const number& value)
{
  return std::real(value);
}

template<typename number=double>
number
compute_number(const number& x, const number& y)
{
  if (make_real<number>(x) < 1.0)
    return x;
  else
    return y;
}

int main()
{

  std::cout << "Evaluate function with double" << std::endl;
  std::cout << compute_number(3.0, 4.0) << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Evaluate function with complex number" << std::endl;
  std::cout << compute_number(3.0+2i, 4.0-2i) << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

**EDIT**: I have improved my code based on C++20 concepts and function overloading. I think there might be no way to avoid the `make_real` call in the if statement, since `std::complex` does not support any comparison operations.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <complex>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std::complex_literals;

double make_real(const std::complex<double>& value)
{
  return std::real(value);
}

double make_real(const double& value)
{
  return value;
}

template <typename T>
struct is_complex_floating_point : public std::false_type {};

template <typename T>
struct is_complex_floating_point<std::complex<T>>
    : public std::bool_constant<std::is_floating_point_v<T>>
{};

template <typename T>
concept real_or_complex_floating_point =
    std::floating_point<T> || 
    is_complex_floating_point<std::remove_const_t<T>>::value;

template<real_or_complex_floating_point number>
number
compute_number(const number& x, const number& y)
{
  if (make_real(x) < 1.0) // is there a way to avoid the make_real call?
    return x;
  else
    return y;
}

int main()
{

  std::cout << "Evaluate function with double" << std::endl;
  std::cout << compute_number(3.0, 4.0) << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Evaluate function with complex number" << std::endl;
  std::cout << compute_number(3.0+2i, 4.0-2i) << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Smarter in which ways?

Comment: default in `typename number=double` is useless, as `number` is deduced.

Comment: C++20 concept might force number to be only `double` or `complex<double>`. (old SFINAE way would be very verbose for that :-/ )

Comment: "Is there a smarter way than the one below" - What's wrong with your way? Maybe you can directly use `std::real()` but seems smart enough, to me.

Comment: If the implementation of your function is different for `double` and for `complex`, do you really need templates? Maybe you can overload the function: `compute(double)` and `compute(complex)`. But as I don't know really what you want to do, maybe you really need templates (in that case can you use `if constexpr`?)

Comment: @Jarod42 @max66: Smarter in the sense (i) I do not want to extract the `std::real` part of a double value (which could be achieved by distinguishing between the `typename` in `make_real` (ii) I though it might be possible to overload the comparison operators to use them also for `double` vs. `std::complex<double>` comparison.

Comment: @Antonio: Overloading is unfortunately not an option since multiple (>100) functions are affected and we want to avoid redundant code.

Comment: *"is there a way to avoid the make_real call?"* Replace it directly by [`std::real`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex/real2) which has overload for both comple and double.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a smarter way than the one below [...]  Smarter in the sense (i) I do not want to extract the std::real part of a double value (which could be achieved by distinguishing between the typename in make_real (ii) I though it might be possible to overload the comparison operators to use them also for double vs. std::complex comparison.

Oh, yes.

I don't if it's a good idea (i don't like the idea of an `operator<()` between a complex and a float) but it's possible.

You can add an `operator<()` as follows

```
bool operator< (std::complex<double> const & cd, double d)
 { return cd.real() < d; }
```

or, if you want it more generic,

```
template <typename D>
bool operator< (std::complex<D> const & cd, D d)
 { return cd.real() < d; }
```

or also

```
template <typename D1, typename D2>
bool operator< (std::complex<D1> const & cd, D2 d)
 { return cd.real() < d; }
```

The following is your example modified.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <complex>
#include <cmath>

bool operator< (std::complex<double> const & cd, double d)
 { return cd.real() < d; }

using namespace std::complex_literals;

template<typename number=double>
number
compute_number(const number& x, const number& y)
 { return x < 1.0 ? x : y; }

int main()
{
  std::cout << "Evaluate function with double" << std::endl;
  std::cout << compute_number(3.0, 4.0) << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Evaluate function with complex number" << std::endl;
  std::cout << compute_number(3.0+2i, 4.0-2i) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much @max66, this goes exactly in the direction I was thinking of.

Comment: It is generally "bad" to overload operator of only foreign types. std might introduce later comparison complex/double making the program ill-formed NDR (ODR violation). a named function seems better.